# How to fetch only inerror and outerror data from rrd file to sql?

Tags: fetch, rrdtool

```
rrdtool info port-6.rrd
```

Here info for port-6.rrd:

[image: Here info for port-6.rrd, and how i can only fetch inerror and out error value to sql?]

Answer (score 0):

You can use rrdtool xport function's main purpose is to write an XML formatted representation of the data stored in one or several RRDs. It can also extract numerical reports. Than you can parse xml file for generating sql statements.

```
$ rrdtool xport \
      --start now-1h --end now \
      DEF:xx=host-inout.lo.rrd:output:AVERAGE \
      DEF:yy=host-inout.lo.rrd:input:AVERAGE \
      CDEF:aa=xx,yy,+,8,* \
      XPORT:xx:"out bytes" \
      XPORT:aa:"in and out bits"
```

The output is enclosed in an xport element and contains two blocks. The first block is enclosed by a meta element and contains some meta data. The second block is enclosed by a data element and contains the data rows.

Comment: Thank's for your help